# JWT interceptor removing contentype header

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm facing that I can not make api calls with the JWT interceptor. I'm getting :

> Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

And I guess is because the JWT interceptor is removing the headers and adding the Bearer stuff, this is my JWT interceptor.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    let credentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("credentials"));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(credentials.accessToken));
    if (credentials && credentials.accessToken) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${credentials.accessToken}`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

I tried with postman and if I leave this header alone it says the same problem, but when I add `Content-Type application/json` it solves the problem, but here in Angular how do I **add** this header but replace?

Comment: What is the issue with adding the `Content-Type` of `application/json`? `setHeaders()` entirely replaces all headers. Are you asking how to just add/set the `authorization` header and keep all other headers that were on the request?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to add the authorization header while preserving existing headers, in this case `content-type`, you could use `request.headers.set()` instead of `setHeaders()` as `setHeaders()` entirely replaces the headers:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    let credentials = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("credentials"));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(credentials.accessToken));
    if (credentials && credentials.accessToken) {
      request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${credentials.accessToken}`)
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to add the header just like you've added the Authorization header:

```js
    if (credentials && credentials.accessToken) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${credentials.accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      });
    }
```

Alternatively, you might want to check the initiator of the request to verify that it's not the one setting incorrect headers in the first place.

Looking at the angular source code ( https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L369 ) setHeaders appears to add or update any existing headers, preserving any you don't mention:

```js
    if (update.setHeaders !== undefined) {
      // Set every requested header.
      headers =
          Object.keys(update.setHeaders)
              .reduce((headers, name) => headers.set(name, update.setHeaders ![name]), headers);
    }
```